# In Chrome, while selecting the selectbox the jquery event is not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#form_field_field_type").live("click", function() {
    console.log("I reach over here");
});
```

Comment: Even though you have answered your own question, it is too vague to be of any help to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the idea... You can fire the change event instead of the click event, so use the following code;

`$("#form_field_field_type").live("change", function() { console.log("I reach over here"); });`

I hope it will work it out!!!

Comment: It works but in need a click event handler. change event always fired when you select an option

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work to me. [This demo shows](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/FyEEx/) that clicking the `<select>` will clone the first one and prepend it to `<body>`.